# unable to save a workspace variable in matlab

Tags: matlab

while trying to save a workspace variable it throws an error in matlab saying I need to switch to -v7.3. I am not sure how to resolve this error since the earlier versions dont support readtable function or xlsread function for an excel file.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html#btox10b-1-version

Comment: @NSK Have you asked this question at MATLAB answers? What was their response?

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to use one of these:

```
save('file.m','var1','var2',-v7.3);
save file.m var1 var2 -v7.3
```

Matlab will save data by default to an older format of *.mat* files. This format does not support variables larger than 2^31 bytes but can be read by old releases of Matlab (pre-R2006b). If you have large variables, you need to switch to format 7.3.

All of this is in the documentation from the save function. Type `doc save` and read.